# Incorrect Store getting loaded

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.1

There are 2 buttons on a `Ext.WIndow`. When i click on the Button 1, the following code get executed.

When i click on the Button 2, the second set of the code gets executed. Both these buttons will load from the `Store`

The problem;

When i click on the 1st Button, The following `console.log` statements gets printed (Which is the way i expected)

```
console.log ('win 1');
console.log('Came win 1');
```

After this when i click on the 2nd Button, I get the incorrect `console.log` gets displayed.

```
console.log ('win 2');
console.log('Came win 1'); // Which is coming from the 1st Buttons Load function.
```

**Button 1**

```
        var personCus= Ext.getStore('Person');
        var record = personCus.getAt(0);
    console.log ('win 1');
    personCus.on('load', function() {
console.log('Came win 1');
        var label= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#win1> #labido')[0];
        label.setText(record1.get('id'));
}
```

**Button 2**

```
        var personCus= Ext.getStore('Person');
        var record = personCus.getAt(0);
    console.log ('win 2');
    personCus.on('load', function() {
console.log('Came win 3');
        var label= Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#win2> #labid1')[0];
        label.setText(record1.get('id'));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think majority of your issue is simply because you're subscribing to the `load` event several times. Basically when you execute Button2 code - store will have two handlers for `load` even and they will run both.

Usually when you subscribe to the `load` event you want to add `{ single: true }` option, so the handler will get called once and will be removed from the store.

```
store.on('load', 
   function() {...},  
   scope /* this or something like it... */,
   { single: true }
);
```